# NotImplementedError: docx2pdf is not implemented for linux as it requires Microsoft Word to be installed

Tags: android, python-docx, chaquopy, docx2pdf

I am using `chaquopy` for converting `.docx` to `.pdf` in android and when I use the following code it crashes the application.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
val py = Python.getInstance()
val myModule = py.getModule("MyModule")
myModule.callAttr("convertDocxToPdf", inputFile.absolutePath, outputFile.absolutePath)
```

**MyModule.py**

```
from docx2pdf import convert

def convertDocxToPdf(input, output):
    convert(input, output)
```

*NOTE: I have also initialized `Python` in `MyApplication.kt`.*

Now my application is building successfully but after running it crashed with the following exceptions:

**Crash logs**:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.tryingsomething, PID: 26841
com.chaquo.python.PyException: NotImplementedError: docx2pdf is not implemented for linux as it requires Microsoft Word to be installed
    at <python>.docx2pdf.convert(__init__.py:108)
    at <python>.MyModule.convertDocxToPdf(MyModule.py:4)
    at <python>.chaquopy_java.call(chaquopy_java.pyx:354)
    at <python>.chaquopy_java.Java_com_chaquo_python_PyObject_callAttrThrowsNative(chaquopy_java.pyx:326)
    at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrowsNative(Native Method)
    at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttrThrows(PyObject.java:232)
    at com.chaquo.python.PyObject.callAttr(PyObject.java:221)
    at com.example.tryingsomething.MainActivity$tryDoc4j$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:133)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
    at com.example.tryingsomething.MainActivity.tryDoc4j(MainActivity.kt:116)
    at com.example.tryingsomething.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:84)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8207)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8191)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3819)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4022)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2336)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@bab8ab3, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

Comment: You did not tell what problem you encountered. Nor is there any question.

Comment: This article might be helpful: [Converting DOCX to PDF using Python](https://michalzalecki.com/converting-docx-to-pdf-using-python/)

Comment: @Emil I want to convert `.docx` to `.pdf` in android application using python because there is no otherway I have found to do it using android SDKs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docx2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/docx2pdf/) page on PyPI clearly states that it only works on Windows and macOS. So you'll have to find a different way of doing this conversion on Android.